# Why can't I use certain variable names in javascript?

Tags: javascript, names

While coding I realized that certain variable names such as `top`, `self`, `left\right` create all sorts of errors when you try to use them. What's the reason behind this in JavaScript, while other languages can use them?

Comment: The underlying language, ECMAScript, has about 40 [*reserved words*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words). The host environment in which it's implemented (typically javascript in a browser) may also have global variables that you need to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use them as **global** variables because there already exist global accessor properties with these names.

- `top` is used to access the top frame.
- `self` is used to access the global object.
- As far as I know there is no problem with `left` and `right`.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'top'));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'self'));
```

Attempting to assign some value to these variables will run the setter, which may not do what you expected. If there is only a getter but no setter, the assignment will be ignored in sloppy mode and throw in strict mode.

There is no problem in using these names as local variables. You should not use global variables anyways.

```js
(function() {
  var top = 123; // local variable
  console.log(top === 123); // true - no problem
})();
var top = 456; // global variable
console.log(top === 456); // false !!!
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems using variables with those names in JavaScript in most cases.

In some environments, some of the names are already used for existing global variables and are read only.

`top` is one such example, it refers to [the top level frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top).

You can still use it as the name of a variable in a non-global context.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you use variables without declaring them with `var`/`let`, and in such circumstances, you modify properties of the global execution environment.

In browser, the global execution environment is `window`, so when you do

```
self = '...'
```

you effectively do

```
window.self = '...'
```

`self`, `top`, `left`, `right` are properties of `window` object which may have certain non-standard behaviors. Many built-in properties of `window` object are in fact implicit setters which do more than setting a variable - they can also modify the current page, navigate etc. Also, many built-in properties of `window` can not be overridden, so assigning to them has no effect.

Contrary, when you do

```
(function() {
    var self = '...'
})()
```

you should not have any problems.

You need a function call to make it work properly, to create a new scope, because in global scope, even with `var`, you'd still implicitly assign a property to `window`.

Comment: `var self` may still be problematic in global context.

Comment: Good point - I was implictly assuming usage inside a function. Updated